# No error output when using subprocess with traceroute

Tags: python, error-handling, subprocess, traceroute

I'm trying to get the error message that is returned when a traceroute fails. For example:

```
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, check_output

try: 
    output = check_output(["traceroute", "error"])
except CalledProcessError as error:
    output = error.output

print "error: {}".format(output)
```

Output:

```
error:
```

I've tried using `output = str(error.output)` but output stays empty. An error message is printed to the terminal when executing the above code, so it should be possible to assign it to a variable, right?

Comment: Call **`check_output`** with **`stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`**. See my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated in: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

> To also capture standard error in the result, use
>   **stderr=subprocess.STDOUT**

**Try:**

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import CalledProcessError, check_output

try: 
    output = check_output(["traceroute", "error"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except CalledProcessError as error:
    output = error

print "error: {}".format(output.output)
```

**Output:**

```
error: traceroute: unknown host error
```

Comment: This is unbelievably awkward, but works. Surprising that `CalledProcessError` does not expose property `error`.